# Selenium Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

How i can push on :

Monitoring

Thanks

I try collect information from Huawei Power System temperature value.

I tried: driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Monitoring").click()

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"Monitoring"}
```

Comment: Element : <li><a value="tree_monitor.asp" onclick="goToTree('tree_monitor.asp')" target="tree"><span>Monitoring</span></a></li>

Comment: Post the URL, the code you've tried and explain the issue clearly.

Comment: I try push the button with such code:

Comment: <li><a value="tree_monitor.asp" onclick="goToTree('tree_monitor.asp')" target="tree"><span>Monitoring</span></a></li>

Comment: This code does nor work:

Comment: I tried: driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Monitoring").click()

Answer (score 0):

Try finding the link by an attribute like `value` or `onclick`, the value must be unique in the entire html

By value:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@value='tree_monitor.asp']").click()
```

By onclick:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@onclick='goToTree(\'tree_monitor.asp\')']").click()
```